# Finding shapes after merging together contours with opencv

Tags: opencv

I would like to find specific shapes (circles and the triangles) in the following image there are:
**Two triangles and two circles in different sizes**
[image]

I have used the:

```
cv2.findContours(image=current_bw_img, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

for getting all 8 contours.

Afterwards I have laid on each blank canvas a subset of contours since some of the contours **are part of** a recognizable shape, so this way I managed to get a recognizable shapes (triangles and circles).

I have done it in a non efficiently manner (2^8), have generated the whole powerset groups of contours even though there are contours which are disjointed, not adjacent to each other which should be ignored. I guess a more correct approach would be to find the nearby contours.

```
def check_all_combinations(current_bw_img, all_contours):
     contours_ids = range(len(all_contours))
     contours_combinations_id = list(powerset(contours_ids))
     for img_id, relevant_contours in enumerate(contours_combinations_id):
          shape_size = current_bw_img.shape
          img_blank_bw = np.ones((shape_size[0], shape_size[1], 1), np.uint8) * 255
          for cnt_id in relevant_contours:
                cv2.drawContours(image=img_blank_bw, contours=[all_contours[cnt_id]], contourIdx=0, color=0, thickness=-1)
                cv2.imshow(winname="img_blank_bw", mat=img_blank_bw)

          img_name = "img_" + str(img_id) + ".png"
          cv2.imwrite(filename=img_name,img=img_blank_bw)
```

For example I got this image (one image out of 256 subgroups) which is invalid, since they don't form a **single** shape (**NOT adjacent contours**)

[image]

Is there a much better approach?

I'll be glad to hear,
Thank you!!

Comment: `I have done it in a non efficiently manner (2^8), have generated the whole superset groups of shapes` Can you elaborate on this, or are you describing the complexity of the `findContours` function?

Comment: Sure I'll elaborate, after I have found the contours with `findContours` , I have generated (2^8) subsets of contours for checking which subset constructs a recognizable shape.

Comment: `I have generated (2^8) subsets of contours for checking which subset constructs a recognizable shape` Could you please post the code for this as well?

Comment: Yep have posted the code, thank you!

Comment: Can you check if this could be of some help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832959/overlapping-shapes-recognition-opencv ?

Comment: Thank you, I have read the solution in the the link you gave here, but I'm looking for a way to retrieve only the adjacent contours.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "adjacent contours"? Glancing at you code, it seems as if you are extracting all shapes present in the image

Comment: I have now added an example for your question regarding "adjacent contours". I hope this is more clear now, thumbs up!

Comment: Would categorising the edges of each contour help, i.e. as either an arc or a straight line? And maybe you can identify edges which have a shared end, and then looking for triangles involves making all the combinations of edges which are a) straight and b) form a closed shape (i.e. all have shared ends), looking for circles involves making all the combinations of edges which are a) arcs, and b) make a closed shape.

Comment: Or maybe don’t bother with countours and just use opencv HoughCircle and HoughLinesP? In the end this will differentiate arcs from lines...

Comment: @barny I'll be glad if you could elaborate a bit more about "identify edges which have a shared end" (each contour holds about more then 200 points around it's perimeter). thank you!

Comment: Maybe using the image of each contour you can use `goodFeaturesToTrack` to find corners, and/or houghlines for circles and lines - the aim being to turn each contour into a closed series of segments (either lines or arcs)? And having got these segments then look for where ends of segments either coincide with other ends or intersect with other segments. But I don’t have a solution or perhaps I’d give you an answer. However it might be simplest to not bother with contours but just for circles use HoughCircles (which is easy) or HoughLinesP and some post-processing to try detect triangles.